# Keep a process running throughout docker build process

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to keep a devpi instance running inside a container throughout the build process so subsequent RUN commands can make use of it and populate it's database during the build. e.g

```
FROM centos:centos7 
RUN pip install devpi
RUN devpi-server --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3141
RUN some other task that interacts with devpi-server
...
```

Is this possible? I've been unable to get it working so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to add a seperate shell script that both started devpi-server and performed the commands that interacted with it. Then I can start the process and interact with it within the same RUN command.

```
FROM centos:centos7 
RUN pip install devpi
ADD start-devpi.sh
RUN chmod +x start-devpi.sh
RUN ./start-devpi.sh
```

Where start-devpi.sh looks like

```bash
devpi-server --host=0.0.0.0 &
sleep 15 #wait for the server to come online
put further commands that use the running devpi-server instance here
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you want to run a certain command in the background you might need to run:

```sh
nohup command &
```

but in your case since you want to run it in background during image build time this might help you:

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y inetutils-ping
# Using sleep will give the command some time to be executed completely
RUN sleep 10 ; ping localhost -c 3 > xxx.log
```

As you can see I am running a sleep command and ping command simultaneously by separating them with `;` let's say in your example the estimated time to populate its database during the build might take around **2mins** so setting sleep time close to that interval would solve ur problem.

> PS: Make sure to know the difference between RUN and CMD, since docker build will actually create a temporary container to test the RUN commands then remove it once the build is done.

Comment: Your method didn't quite work, however it gave me some ideas and I got there in the end. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If this was helpful then you could upvote it so it shows that it's at least useful and thanks.